# How do I remove a value from a data frame row if it does not match with a dictionary mapping?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have row in my data frame that is composed of numbers (some of them are ID's but others are just irrelevant numbers) and I want to create a new column with the names that match those ID's, but drop the irrelevant numbers.

I have a dictionary that matches them, such as:

```
id_numbers = {"001" : "Matt", "002":"Chris", "003":"Jana"}
```

Right now, I am just using the following code (which matches the numbers and names well) but I also copy all the irrelevant numbers in the column. How do I copy to the new column ONLY the numbers that were matched with a name in the dictionary?

```
df['names'] = df['numbers'].replace(id_numbers )
```

After that, I would also like to delete the numbers from the number column that are not in the dictionary. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['names'] = df['numbers'].map(id_numbers)
```

Or use:

```
df['names'] = df['numbers'].replace(list(id_numbers.keys()), list(id_numbers.values()))
```

Comment: wow cool, `When arg is a dictionary, values in Series that are not in the dictionary (as keys) are converted to NaN`, perfect.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 Yeah :-)

Comment: @Adam.Er8 Everyone learns new stuff everyday, the `replace` i learned from jezrael